# Identify window title with two class names using OR condition

Tags: autoit

I am using autoit to upload files in my web application. I am planning to integrate Selenium and AutoIt as mentioned in https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

My problem right now is when I click on upload button In chrome Upload window title is coming as "Open" and in Firefox title is coming as "File Upload". So my question is is there any way in autoit to find window title using different values. i.e. "Open" OR "File Upload"

Here is my code to upload file in chrome

```
WinWait("Open", "", 60)
WinActivate("Open")
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", "C:\abc.war")
ControlClick("Open","", "Button1")
```

Here is my code to upload file in firefox

```
WinWait("File Upload", "", 60)
WinActivate("File Upload")
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1", "C:\abc.war")
ControlClick("File Upload","", "Button1")
```

Comment: Here is a general solution, not detailed enough to add as an answer... But if you can detect the environment, do an if or switch statement based on what environment you have (chrome, firefox). Then set a variable `winTitle` for the different cases. Then you can pass `winTitle` wherever it's needed... `WinActivate(winTitle)` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in order to find the desired window:

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4)

$handle = WinGetHandle("[REGEXPTITLE:(?:Open|File Upload)]")

;In case window was not found
If @error Then Exit

WinWait($handle, "", 60)
WinActivate($handle)
ControlFocus($handle,"","Edit1")
ControlSetText($handle,"","Edit1", "C:\abc.war")
ControlClick($handle,"", "Button1")
```

However, this is still not a very robust way. Some other suggestions that could be considered in addition:

- Check the window class. The upload window is a dialog box, so its class will be `#32770` according to [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes)
- Check the currently active window using `WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")`